# Packet tracer is changing my addresses ipv4

Tags: cisco, routing, network, layer3, rip

Could someone help me with this?
I have a subnet with the ip: 172.16.193.0 in the fastethernet 0/0 of my router and when I go to put it in RIP the Packet tracer is changing it for another ip:172.16.0.0
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text from the `show running-config` command and paste it into the question and use the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`) that is right next to the image feature you used.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use RIPv2. RIPv1 defaults to the obsolete classful addressing (`172.16.0.0/16`).

Use the `version 2` router command:

```
router rip
  version 2
end
```

All the RIP routers need to use RIPv2.

---

FYI,

The network address for `172.16.193.0/18` is `172.16.192.0/18`, and `172.16.193.0` is the 256<sup>th</sup> usable host address in the `172.16.192.0/18` network (usable addresses are `172.16.192.1` to `172.16.255.254`).

Comment: How do I change from RIP 1 to RIP2? I have no idea I'm a super rookie

Comment: As I explained, use the `version 2` router command.